# Open Data management platform for Aligned Text translations

Tags: open-source, web-apps, document-management, translation

I am currently translating documents from Standard Language (e.g., English) to Easy Language (e.g., Simple English). I want to give people open data access to the texts. Ideally, both versions of the texts are aligned and linked, so that the user can compare the two versions. My target group are people with disabilities, who just want the information in Easy Language and additionally a scientific audience, who wants to do some research on the data. So, it should be possible to download a single text or do a bulk download.

I am looking for an existing platform, where I can upload my data or a self-hostable application/servlet, which can be accessed via the browser by the user. But I would definitely prefer to upload my data to an existing platform.

Furthermore, I have a technical background, but my users won't. So, the setup and maintenance can be complicated, but the experience for the end user should be hassle-free. If I go for a self-hosted platform, I won't necessarily need any collaboration features or possibilities for other people to upload a translation.

I am looking forward to your recommendations :)